# How to get sound/audio in the rear loudspeakers when using Adobe Flash Player?

Tags: audio, flash, speakers

When playing sound within Adobe Flash Player there is no sound in the rear speakers in a 5.1 setup.

I am aware the output is only stereo encoded (2 channels). What I am trying to achieve in Flash is the same as other applications do - basically output any left channel sound to both front and rear left speakers and vice-versa on the right hand side.

OS: Windows Vista; Flash 10.2.152.32

Comment: Which sound card (and driver) are you using?